# Drupal Views - Start at end of pager

Tags: drupal, view

Is there a way to have the view default to the end of a pager list rather than the beginning. Ie - think of a web comic where I would want to display the last item first and have them go back if they want.

I wouldn't want to just list in DESC order because the pager would list the older entries as "NEXT"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the [Views Simple Pager](http://drupal.org/project/views_simple_pager) module might do what you are looking for.